# TypeError when calling Spark MLlib LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to call `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train` from Spark MLlib with a training data for solving multi-class logistic regression . My training set data is represented as:

```
trainingData = sXYdf.rdd.map(lambda x: reg.LabeledPoint(x[0]-1,x[1:]))
trainingData.take(2)
```

The out of the LabeledPoints (2 rows) are: (  I am not outputting the full label and features as it is 2x401 label-feature matrix with feature occupies from col 1-401 while the label is in col 0. The same data looks like this:-

```
[LabeledPoint(9.0, [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,8.56059679589e-06,1.94035947712e-06,-0.00073743872549,-0.0081340379902,-0.0186104473039,-0.0187412865354,-0.018757250817,-0.0190963541667...])]
```

Now when I call

```
lrm=LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData,numClasses=10)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-9b0c5530b34b> in <module>()
      1 #lr=LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.0, elasticNetParam=0.0)
----> 2 lrm=LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData,numClasses=10)

C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\classification.py in train(cls, data, iterations, initialWeights, regParam, regType, intercept, corrections, tolerance, validateData, numClasses)
    396                 else:
    397                     initialWeights = [0.0] * len(data.first().features) * (numClasses - 1)
--> 398         return _regression_train_wrapper(train, LogisticRegressionModel, data, initialWeights)
    399 
    400 

C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\regression.py in _regression_train_wrapper(train_func, modelClass, data, initial_weights)
    214         weights, intercept, numFeatures, numClasses = train_func(
    215             data, _convert_to_vector(initial_weights))
--> 216         return modelClass(weights, intercept, numFeatures, numClasses)
    217     else:
    218         weights, intercept = train_func(data, _convert_to_vector(initial_weights))

C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\classification.py in __init__(self, weights, intercept, numFeatures, numClasses)
    174             self._dataWithBiasSize = self._coeff.size / (self._numClasses - 1)
    175             self._weightsMatrix = self._coeff.toArray().reshape(self._numClasses - 1,
--> 176                                                                 self._dataWithBiasSize)
    177 
    178     @property

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

ADDED MORE LOGS:-
looks like worker thread creation had problems..

```
17/07/15 19:59:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 123 contains a task of very large size (17658 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
17/07/15 19:59:24 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 123.0 (TID 123)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
        ... 27 more
17/07/15 19:59:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 123.0 (TID 123, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
        ... 27 more

17/07/15 19:59:24 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 123.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sunil\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Sunil\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 211, in <module>
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
[I 20:01:12.525 NotebookApp] Saving file at /mltclasspyspark.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that [there is a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20862) in Spark 2.1.1 producing the above error with Python 3 (I cannot reproduce it with Python 2.7).

So, if you cannot upgrade to Spark 2.1.2 or 2.2, where the issue has been reportedly resolved, or use Python 2.7 instead, what I **suggest** is modifying your `map` function as follows, so that your labels are now integers instead of floats (haven't tested it though):

```
trainingData = sXYdf.rdd.map(lambda x: reg.LabeledPoint(int(x[0]-1),x[1:]))
```

Comment: unfortunately typecasting it to int didn't help. Let me try to upgrade the spark and give it a shot.

Comment: appreciate your help. upgrade to spark 2.2.0 did work , though I kept the typecasting .